# Python 2.7 web-scraping - list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to python and web-scraping. I'm trying to scrape http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/all_league.html for some analysis and only gotten so far. With the below code I'm able to scrape only 3 rows and getting 'list index out of range' error while assigning the year. Any help/tips appreciated.

```
r = requests.get('http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/all_league.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text.replace('&nbsp;','').replace('&gt;','').encode('ascii','ignore'),"html.parser")
all_league_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['year','team','player']) 


stw_list = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'stw'}) # Find all 'stw's'
for stw in stw_list:
    table = stw.find('table', attrs = {'class':'no_highlight stats_table'})
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        col = row.findAll('td')
        year = col[0].find(text=True)
        print year
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the rows don't have `td`, so you try to get element 0 of empty list.

Do:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/all_league.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text.replace('&nbsp;','').replace('&gt;','').encode('ascii','ignore'),"html.parser")
all_league_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['year','team','player']) 

stw_list = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'stw'}) # Find all 'stw's'
for stw in stw_list:
    table = stw.find('table', attrs = {'class':'no_highlight stats_table'})
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        col = row.findAll('td')
        if col:
            year = col[0].find(text=True)
            print year
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the grey line that is a tr and is empty.
Do a check if col

```
col = row.findAll('td')
    if col:
        year = col[0].find(text=True)
        print year
```

and gives results correct

```
2014-15
2014-15
2014-15
2013-14
2013-14
2013-14
2012-13
2012-13
etc
```